# Top, Limit, Offset... I can't show a registers in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a cursor to loop through two filtered records, it does fine. But within each record I need to show the 5 worst inventory values. It only shows me one, I've tried TOP, (LIMIT doesn't work in SQL Server), and now also OFFSET and FETCH NEXT, but it still only shows me the first record.

Does anyone see any logical solution?
I thought it was easy, but I can't find the reason.

```
    DECLARE @Counter AS INT = 1;
    DECLARE @LocationBuffer  AS NVARCHAR(30);
    DECLARE @QuantityBuffer  AS INT;
    DECLARE @MinDateMovements  AS DATE;
    DECLARE @TopDateMovements  AS DATE;
    
    DECLARE @DateMovementsTopWorst AS DATE;
    DECLARE @InventoryOnSiteTopWorst AS NUMERIC;
    DECLARE @FamilyTopWorst AS VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @BufferTopWorst AS NUMERIC;
    DECLARE @SkuTopWorst AS VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @LocationTopWorst AS VARCHAR(50); 

    DECLARE cursorr CURSOR LOCAL
            FOR SELECT amor.LOCATION, COUNT(amor.INACTIVE),
                MIN(UPDATE_MOVEMENTS), MAX(UPDATE_MOVEMENTS)
            FROM TFSCM_CLI_BUFFER AS amor
            WHERE amor.INACTIVE = 0 AND amor.FAMILY IN
                    (SELECT fam.CDBUFFER_FAMILY 
                     FROM TFSCM_CLI_BUFFER_FAMILY AS fam
                     WHERE fam.REPLENISHMENT_MODE = 'M' OR fam.REPLENISHMENT_MODE = 'I')
            GROUP BY amor.LOCATION;

    OPEN cursorr
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursorr
    INTO @LocationBuffer, @QuantityBuffer, @MinDateMovements, @TopDateMovements;
    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0) 
        BEGIN

            PRINT 'Locations: '
                + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @LocationBuffer );
            PRINT 'Buffers (manual and intermediate) actives: '
                + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @QuantityBuffer );
            PRINT 'Movements dates: '
                + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @MinDateMovements )
                + ' and '
                + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @TopDateMovements);
            PRINT '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'    

            SELECT  @SkuTopWorst= SKU,
                    @BufferTopWorst = BUFFER,
                    @FamilyTopWorst = FAMILY,
                    @InventoryOnSiteTopWorst = TOTAL_INVENTORY_ON_SITE,
                    @DateMovementsTopWorst = UPDATE_MOVEMENTS,
                    @LocationTopWorst = LOCATION
                FROM TFSCM_CLI_BUFFER
                WHERE LOCATION = @LocationBuffer
                ORDER BY TOTAL_INVENTORY_ON_SITE
                OFFSET  5 ROWS 
                FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY 
            
            PRINT ' SKU: '
            + '         Size: '
            + '         Family: '
            + '         Inventory: '
            + '         Movement Date: '

            PRINT   @SkuTopWorst
                    + '     '
                    + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @BufferTopWorst)
                    + '             '
                    +  @FamilyTopWorst
                    + '                 '
                    + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @InventoryOnSiteTopWorst)
                    + '                 '
                    +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @DateMovementsTopWorst);

            PRINT '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
            FETCH NEXT FROM cursorr INTO @LocationBuffer, @QuantityBuffer, @MinDateMovements, @TopDateMovements
        END
    CLOSE cursorr
    DEALLOCATE cursorr
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `select @var1 = value1, @var2 = value2, ...` your variables will each be populated with exactly 1 value.

If you want to print 5 values, you'll need to cursor through the 5 records, and fetch each set of values into your variables, and then print them.

Or you can use string concatenation to build the entire list into a string with cr/lf and print the clob:

```sql
set @Info = (
    SELECT top 5
           cast(SKU    as char(15))
         + cast(BUFFER as char(15))
         + cast(FAMILY as char(17))
    -- rest of the columns here
         + char(13)+char(10)
    FROM TFSCM_CLI_BUFFER
    WHERE LOCATION = @LocationBuffer
    ORDER BY TOTAL_INVENTORY_ON_SITE
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
).value('.','nvarchar(max)');

print @Info;
```

which uses [`for xml path`](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation) to concatenate the strings.

If you're on SQL Server 2017+, you can instead use [`string_agg()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: ¿This is STUFF?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question...[`STUFF()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) replaces text in a string.  It's often used in conjunction with the above string concatenation, where the first item in the select list is a delimiter.  After the string is built, you can `stuff(@var,1,1,'')` to remove the first character in the string.